# Physical meaning of Laue's condition for diffraction from crystals

Tags: solid-state-physics, diffraction, lattice-model, x-ray-crystallography

The Laue's condition for diffraction is that scattering vector is equal to reciprocal lattice vectors $\mathbf{G}$. But how can a 'particular vector' equal a set of vectors? The reciprocal lattice vectors are $\mathbf{G}=p\mathbf{b}_1+q\mathbf{b}_2+r\mathbf{b}_3$ where $p,q,r$ are integers and $\mathbf{b}_1,\mathbf{b}_2,\mathbf{b}_3$ are primitive vectors of reciprocal space. So how can this whole set is equal to scattering vector?
Sorry if the question is dumb I am new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how can a 'particular vector' equal a set of vectors=

Of course it is mathematical nonsense to say,
a *particular* vector $\Delta\mathbf{k}$ is *equal* to a set of vectors.
$$\Delta\mathbf{k} = \{ \mathbf{G}=p\mathbf{b}_1+q\mathbf{b}_2+r\mathbf{b}_3
\; |\; p,q,r \text{ integers} \}$$

What is meant is this:
A particular vector $\Delta\mathbf{k}$ is *an element of* this set of vectors.
$$\Delta\mathbf{k} \in \{ \mathbf{G}=p\mathbf{b}_1+q\mathbf{b}_2+r\mathbf{b}_3
\; |\; p,q,r \text{ integers} \}$$

Physically speaking Laue's condition says:
Only those scattering vectors $\Delta\mathbf{k}$ occur which are an
integer combination of the primitive vectors of reciprocal space.
$$\Delta\mathbf{k}=p\mathbf{b}_1+q\mathbf{b}_2+r\mathbf{b}_3$$